# Will formatting my hard drive to install Ubuntu also get rid of my recovery partition?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, partitioning

I am looking to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer and am thinking about wiping the drive but I am worried that if I wipe the drive it will also remove my recovery partition.  The recovery partition came standard on my laptop so I don't want it gone (the computer didn't come with recovery disks).

Will the Ubuntu installation remove my recovery partition and is this even a real concern?

Answer (score 1):

When you are installing ubuntu, you have the option to manually manage the partitions. If you don't delete the recovery partition there, then it won't be wiped out. Moreover, if you choose to 'install alongside windows', it is safe to. I do not, however, know if 'erase entire disk' deletes the recovery partitions or not

Comment: what would i choose to do that

Comment: Erase entire Disk DOES ERASE the recovery partition

Comment: Hit the install button. You will be presented with buttons representing 'alongside windows','entire disk' e.t.c. Go for alongside windows. Just keep in mind that if you're using windows 8, only the 64 bit version of ubuntu will workl

Comment: it says erase entire disk and install ubuntu

Comment: That's all? Using windows 7 or 8? Some people have had this problem when they use ubuntu 64bit. Windows is detected again when you use the 32 bit version of ubuntu. Can you try it?

Comment: 14.04 is the only version of ubuntu that has worked on my laptop and the 32bit version isnt out yet